# How to assign varibale in h<h3> tag in PHP

Tags: php, html, variables, tags

I am trying to assign a PHP variable in h3 tag. Below is my tag:

```
'Summary' => [
  'data' => '<div class="page_sum"><h1>Scan Summary:</h1></div>
            <div class="page_sum">
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;">Total Found:<?php echo $totalFind ?></h3>
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;">Total Dir: 53</h3><br/>
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Planned Sync Files: 175</h3>
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Actual Synced: 175 </h3><br/>
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Missing Synced Files: 0</h3><br/>',
  'colspan' => 5, 'class' => array('foo', 'bar'),
],
```

But it does not allow me to do that, how can I assign a variable value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
<h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;">Total Found:<?php echo $totalFound ?></h3>
```

?

After your edit:

```
'Summary' => [
  'data' => '<div class="page_sum"><h1>Scan Summary:</h1></div>
            <div class="page_sum">
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;">Total Found: '.$totalFind.'
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;">Total Dir: 53</h3><br/>
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Planned Sync Files: 175</h3>
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Actual Synced: 175 </h3><br/>
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Missing Synced Files: 0</h3><br/>',
  'colspan' => 5, 'class' => array('foo', 'bar'),
],
```

Comment: Yes i already tried like above but It does not display variable values

Answer (score 0):

```
'Summary' => [
  'data' => '<div class="page_sum"><h1>Scan Summary:</h1></div>
            <div class="page_sum">
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;">Total Found:'.$totalFind.'</h3>
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;">Total Dir: 53</h3><br/>
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Planned Sync Files: 175</h3>
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Actual Synced: 175 </h3><br/>
                <h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Missing Synced Files: 0</h3><br/>',
  'colspan' => 5, 'class' => array('foo', 'bar'),
],
```